# making movie monster, need so advice about roars

Tags: sound-design, mixing

so i'm in the middle of making a future monster movie, and i want to learn how to make a roar sound both powerful and terrifying. how would i go about doing that? are there any websites to produce sounds and mix them up to create a roar? Just so you know my monster is a reptile mammal hybrid. looks like Godzilla and king kong had a baby.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the wonderful world of creature sound design! Surprise! There are no short cuts.

Nope, no websites to produce sounds, no magic plugins to make your monster come to life.

It's up to you to make that happen. I suggest you do a LOT of research into how the best in the business have worked their magic, ie. Ben Burtt, Gary Rydstrom, Erik Aadahl, Ethan Van der Ryn, Dave Farmer, Tim Walson, the list goes on. There is a surprising amount of material online that will get you started on your journey.

To effectively create your own creature sound design, I recommend you buy the best microphone and recorder you can afford (see this forum for a wealth of posts on the subject) and get busy recording everything you can that you feel may help bring your monster to life. The building blocks of your design do not always need to be rooted in reality. For example, the original Toho Godzilla roar was sourced from the sound of a resin-coated glove being rubbed against the strings of a double bass. Things like metal, dry ice and friction are very useful ingredients with which to start.